# C# Json parsing - array of objects and access array

Tags: c#, arrays, json

If I have a json array of objects, in python I'd be able to do

```
var arr = json.loads(string)
```

and then be able to access the first element (`arr[0]`).

However in C# when I parse the json string using either `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` or `JArray.Parse`, it gets turned into an object:

```
{
  [
    {blah: ""}, 
    {blah: ""} 
  ]
}
```

and so I can't access the first element, like how I would do it in python, because of the object surrounding the array.
I get the error:

```
 error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'
```

Is there something I'm missing? Ideally I'd like to just be able to easily access the first element of the array of objects, without having to do any for loops, etc.

Comment: The JSON posted in the question is invalid.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli there no JSON posted in the question as I can see - do you mean "turned into an object"? (which seem to be demonstration of JArray object OP got, not a JSON they have...)

Comment: The json you posted is an object wrapped around your Array. So if you can change the json you should either remove the braces around your square brackets, or change it to: {"Array":[...]},  deserialize ist as Jobject/dynamic and access ist by value["Array"][0] for an object in the array.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve dynamic (run-time) typing as in Python just use `dynamic`:

```
var r = ((dynamic)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("[1,2]"))[1]; // 2
```

Note that usually you would deserialize Json into strongly typed object and work with it, but that would be C# way and not Python-like you are asking about.